# Make GTK Entry box smaller

Tags: gtk, julia

I am trying to make a GUI program in Julia using Gtk.  My program includes a large number of GtkEntry boxes.  However, I am running into space issues because the Entry boxes have a lot of internal padding around the actual characters.  I would like to reduce, at least, the top and bottom whitespace.  I have tried to use the `setproperty!()` function to change the `height-request` value, but that seems to be only able to make the box bigger, not smaller.  Additionally, the `margin`, `margin-top`, etc. fields are all set to 0 by default.  Again, I can make them bigger but not smaller.

Is this possible to fix?  I have included below a minimal working example, a screenshot, and a Julia REPL output displaying the available properties.

**Edit:** 
I have also tried using a css file (test.css) with the contents

```
entry {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Julia 0.6.0 code:

```
using Gtk

win = GtkWindow("Example")

sb = GtkGrid()
function sb_entry(label)
    frame = GtkFrame(label)
    entry = GtkEntry()
    setproperty!(entry, :input_purpose, 2)
    push!(frame, entry)
    return frame
end
sb_rows = sb_entry("rows")
sb_cols = sb_entry("cols")
sb_row_off = sb_entry("row off")
sb_col_off = sb_entry("col off")
sb[1,1] = sb_rows
sb[2,1] = sb_cols
sb[1,2] = sb_row_off
sb[2,2] = sb_col_off
setproperty!(sb, :column_homogeneous, true)
setproperty!(sb, :column_spacing, 5)
setproperty!(sb, :row_spacing, 5)

push!(win, sb)

### begin edit (css)

screen   = Gtk.GAccessor.screen(win)
provider = GtkCssProviderLeaf(filename="/path/to/test.css")

ccall((:gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen, Gtk.libgtk), Void,
        (Ptr{Void}, Ptr{GObject}, Cuint),
        screen, provider, 1)

### end edit (css)

showall(win)

if !isinteractive()
    c = Condition()
    signal_connect(win, :destroy) do widget
        notify(c)
    end
    wait(c)
end
```

[image: Minimal Example]

```
julia> sb_row_off[1]

Gtk.GtkEntryLeaf(editing-canceled=FALSE, name="", parent, width-request=-1,
height-request=-1, visible=TRUE, sensitive=TRUE, app-paintable=FALSE,
can-focus=TRUE, has-focus=FALSE, is-focus=TRUE, focus-on-click=TRUE,
can-default=FALSE, has-default=FALSE, receives-default=FALSE, composite-child=FALSE,
style, events=0, no-show-all=FALSE, has-tooltip=FALSE, tooltip-markup=NULL,
tooltip-text=NULL, window, opacity=1.000000, double-buffered, halign=GTK_ALIGN_FILL,
valign=GTK_ALIGN_FILL, margin-left, margin-right, margin-start=0, margin-end=0,
margin-top=0, margin-bottom=0, margin=0, hexpand=FALSE, vexpand=FALSE,
hexpand-set=FALSE, vexpand-set=FALSE, expand=FALSE, scale-factor=2, buffer,
cursor-position=0, selection-bound=0, editable=TRUE, max-length=0, visibility=TRUE,
has-frame=TRUE, inner-border, invisible-char=9679, activates-default=FALSE,
width-chars=-1, max-width-chars=-1, scroll-offset=0, text="", xalign=0.000000,
truncate-multiline=FALSE, shadow-type, overwrite-mode=FALSE, text-length=0,
invisible-char-set=FALSE, caps-lock-warning=TRUE, progress-fraction=0.000000,
progress-pulse-step=0.100000, primary-icon-pixbuf, secondary-icon-pixbuf,
primary-icon-stock, secondary-icon-stock, primary-icon-name=NULL,
secondary-icon-name=NULL, primary-icon-gicon, secondary-icon-gicon,
primary-icon-storage-type=GTK_IMAGE_EMPTY,
secondary-icon-storage-type=GTK_IMAGE_EMPTY, primary-icon-activatable=TRUE,
secondary-icon-activatable=TRUE, primary-icon-sensitive=TRUE,
secondary-icon-sensitive=TRUE, primary-icon-tooltip-text=NULL,
secondary-icon-tooltip-text=NULL, primary-icon-tooltip-markup=NULL,
secondary-icon-tooltip-markup=NULL, im-module=NULL, placeholder-text=NULL,
completion, input-purpose=GTK_INPUT_PURPOSE_DIGITS, input-hints=GTK_INPUT_HINT_NONE,
attributes, populate-all=FALSE, tabs)
```

Comment: You might be able to do it with CSS.

Comment: @andlabs I tried that, but I couldn't figure out how to load CSS.  I didn't see anything about it in the Julia GTK documentation and when I tried to reproduce the CSS unit test from the GTK.jl github repo, it did not do what it was supposed to.

Comment: You load CSS by using GtkCssProvider and apply it through GtkStyleContext, either on a single widget or to a GDK screen. What do you mean by "it did not do what it was supposed to"? Can you link the code? What version of GTK+ do you have?

Comment: @andlabs My libgtk version is 3.22.16.  I ran the code in lines 738 - 750 of [this](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Gtk.jl/blob/77cf6dca186571781c889e9000d9599b13010548/test/gui.jl) file, replacing line 738 with a string to the path where I downloaded the "style_test.css" file, and preceding the whole thing with `using Gtk.ShortNames`.  It looks like it calls both of the functions you mentioned.  The resulting window text was the same as if I had never used the css file in the first place: small black text, not large blue text.  I am using Julia 0.6.0.

Comment: Ah, that CSS file hasn't been updated to use the new node names of GTK+ 3.20 and 3.22. Simply changing `GtkLabel` to `label` there should make it work...

Comment: @andlabs Thanks!  That seemed to do the trick.  Now back to the original question -- I have tried setting `entry { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; }` in the css file, but none of these options seem to have any effect on the output gui.  (I edited the question to include this new information)

Comment: Turns out I can use the css settings to make entry boxes smaller, but not on macOS.  When I tried the same code on Ubuntu, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 6):

`entry { min-height: 0px; }` allows it to be as small as possible. Adjust size as required.

Comment: Brilliant. Can't see it documented anywhere, but if it works, it works! You saved my day.